# Do we have to use transaction every time while using with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I had read many websites and they says that using transaction is optional  as hibernate application manages transaction in their own application code.

But when I check code it always uses transaction?

What is the correct methodology?

```
    Configuration c = new Configuration();
    c.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();

    Session s = sf.openSession();

    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    //some code
    t.commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation) says:

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No communication with the database can occur outside of a database transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for read-only operations. Depending on your isolation level and database capabilities this might not be required, but there is no downside if you always demarcate transactions explicitly. Certainly, a single database transaction is going to perform better than many small transactions, even for reading data.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following tag in hibernate property file

```
 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class ">thread</prop>
```

or if you are using spring, then you can use @Transactional annotation to handle the transaction automatically.